# Format date as day of week

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table which has amongst others a date column `servdate`.

I use the following query to get me all jobs from within the past week ( a week starts from monday):

```
SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE servdate BETWEEN date('now', 'Weekday 1', '-21 days') AND date('now')
```

I want the query to work exactly the same but instead to return the `servdate` fields as their corresponding day of the week. For example, "monday", instead of "2010-11-28".

Is this possible?

Comment: wallyk's idea is nice but for simplicity I would prefer "sun" "mon" instead of "0" "1"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use an ancillary table as wallyk suggested; or you can use a `case` expression:

```
select _id, busnum, 
  case cast (strftime('%w', servdate) as integer)
  when 0 then 'Sunday'
  when 1 then 'Monday'
  when 2 then 'Tuesday'
  when 3 then 'Wednesday'
  when 4 then 'Thursday'
  when 5 then 'Friday'
  else 'Saturday' end as servdayofweek
from tb1
where ...
```

Comment: Nice addendum.  I couldn't find `case` being supported in the documentation, but I tried it in Firefox and it works fine: `SELECT visit_date, case cast (strftime('%w', visit_date/1000000) as integer)
 when 0 then 'sun' when 1 then 'mon' when 2 then 'tue' when 3 then 'wed' when 4 then 'thu' when 5 then 'fri' when 6 then 'sat' else '???' end as visitdayofweek
FROM moz_historyvisits LIMIT 50`

Comment: Note: For me, this query only returns one single result: a random day of the week. To get results for the entire week, I need to add a group - `group by strftime('%w', servdate)`

Answer (score 10):

Here a suggestion involving less typing than the `CASE ... WHEN` block. Here, the same is done by substring extraction:

```
select substr('SunMonTueWedThuFriSat', 1 + 3*strftime('%w', timestr), 3) as dow
from ...
```

It produces only fixed length abbreviations instead of full weekday names, though. (But sometimes that's enough.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT _id, busnum, date_format(servdate, '%a') as servdayofweek
FROM tb1
WHERE servdate BETWEEN date('now', 'Weekday 1', '-21 days') AND date('now')
```

The %a is the abbreviated day of the week.  See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for other ways to format.

---

edit:

Oops!  Overlooked the sqlite tag.  The above is for MySQL.  For sqlite ([documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)):

```
SELECT _id, busnum, strftime('%w', servdate) as servdayofweek
FROM tb1
WHERE servdate BETWEEN date('now', 'Weekday 1', '-21 days') AND date('now')
```

except this returns the day of week as a value 0 through 6.  Maybe that's good enough?

Comment: hello, i ran the query and got: SQL error: no such function: date_format

Comment: could this code be adpated to return "mon" instead of "1" etc ? :D

Comment: So far, I haven't found a direct way of doing it.  If you can add another table, then it is trivial.