# Select rows where the date is a weekday

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible in SQLite to select rows only if a datetime column is a weekday? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE datetime IS_A_WEEKDAY
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlite return as day of week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319302/sqlite-return-as-day-of-week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question that was already asked:

[sqlite return as day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319302/sqlite-return-as-day-of-week)

Comment: Thanks, used the info there to create my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the info in [sqlite return as day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319302/sqlite-return-as-day-of-week) this is how I solved it:

```
SELECT ..., CAST(strftime('%w', date_column) AS integer) AS dow FROM data WHERE dow >= 1 and dow <= 5;
```