# Android- SQLite query to Order Results by Day using the query builder

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by, query-builder

At the moment i'm currently using the query builder to pull all my records from my database and they are currently organised by day however I its sorts in althabetical order,

```
  public Cursor fetchAll() {

      return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULECODE,
        KEY_DAY, KEY_TIME, KEY_DURATION, KEY_TYPE, KEY_ROOM},null, null, null, null,"Day");
   }
```

I know after some googling, that I need to replace the final section with a custom search order. 
something along the lines of :

```
 select _id, busnum, 
    case cast (strftime('%w', servdate) as integer)
        when 0 then 'Sunday'
        when 1 then 'Monday'
        when 2 then 'Tuesday'
        when 3 then 'Wednesday'
        when 4 then 'Thursday'
         when 5 then 'Friday'
        else 'Saturday' end as servdayofweek
   from tb1
   where ...

   From:
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319302/sqlite-return-as-day-of-week
```

so far i have been unable to figure out how tocombine the two and anyhelp in the right direction would be much aprechiated.

Edit Soloution 
thank you for the help I went with declaring the string and linking to it in the query for anyone that needs something simple this is my final code for it

```
public Cursor fetchAll() {
   String OrderBy ="case Day"+
      " when 'Monday' then 0 "+ 
      " when 'Tuesday' then 1"+
      " when 'Wednesday' then 2"+
      " when 'Thursday' then 3"+
      " when 'Friday' then 5"+
      " end";
 return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_MODULECODE,
        KEY_DAY, KEY_TIME, KEY_DURATION, KEY_TYPE, KEY_ROOM},null, null, null, null,OrderBy );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Day` values are the day names then you want something like this:

```
order by case Day
        when 'Sunday' then 0
        when 'Monday' then 1
        when 'Tuesday' then 2
        ...
        when 'Saturday' then 6
    end
```

in the SQL; keep in mind that you can hand an SQL ORDER BY pretty much any expression. The `orderBy` argument to [`query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) can be any SQL ORDER BY clause (without the `order by`) so you want this big ugly string :

```
"case Day when 'Sunday' then 0 when 'Monday' then 1 ... when 'Saturday' then 6 end"
```

as the last argument to `query`. You'll have to properly fill in the `...` of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot figure out how to pass a complex query through `SQLiteDatabase.query(... lots of variables...)` just pass your select statement as a string with [`SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29).

For example:

```
String query = "select _id, busnum, " +
               " case cast cast (strftime('%w', servdate) as integer) " +
               ...
String[] selectionArgs = new String() { yada, yada, yada }
mDb.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
```