# How to convert individual fields to SQLite date for computing week day?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Having a following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo`(
  `year` INT NOT NULL,
  `month` INT NOT NULL,
  `day` INT NOT NULL,
  `hour` INT NOT NULL,
  `minute` INT NOT NULL,
  `value` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `minute`)
);
```

How to select all the Monday records in SQLite?

Comment: I'd add a column with the weekday.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319302/sqlite-return-as-day-of-week

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. convert the date into a format [understood by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), which requires padding with zeros to the required four/two digit field width to get `YYYY-MM-DD`;
2. then just use `strftime('%w')` to get the week day:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE strftime('%w',
               substr('000' || year,  -4) || '-' ||
               substr('0'   || month, -2) || '-' ||
               substr('0'   || day,   -2)           ) = '1'
```

Comment: Nice `substr` trick for dealing with the zero padding, nicer than the horrendous `case length(month) when 1 then '0' || month else month end` I was thinking of.

Comment: Hi. I've finally came back to this task and tried your answer on practice and it doesn't work actually - says "wrong number of arguments to function substr()".

Comment: Works for me. Is your SQLite older than 3.5.2?

Comment: Indeed it is, thanks again.

Comment: A curious detail: I've just discovered that `strftime` returns the day number not as an integer but as a string! As I actually do a bit more logic, I've spent half an hour debugging my query to find out that the result of strftime is always greater than any number (regardless to what does it equal itself) and why %-)