# Why does SQLite report wrong number of arguments to function substr() in my case?

Tags: sql, sqlite, substr

I am trying to use [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000819/274627) but it reports "wrong number of arguments to function substr()".

I've then tried to test the following a simple query:

```
SELECT substr('000' || '4',  -4);
```

and it throws the same error.

SQlite documentation says `substr` accepts 2 or 3 arguments and here I give it 2 but it still complains.

Any idea why?

UPDATE:

To make it even clearer, I've tried executing simply

```
SELECT substr('abcdefg',  4);
```

and it gives the same  error.

UPDATE2:

In fact, I was using `SQLite Administrator 0.8.3.2` (which uses pretty old SQLite library - SQLite 3.5.1) to run the queries. Now I have tried using bare sqlite3.exe (SQLite 3.7.15) - everything works just fine.

Comment: Which SQLite version are you using? (run `select sqlite_version();`)

Comment: I am using SQLite Administrator 0.8.3.2, `sqlite_version()` returns `3.5.1`. I think this is the answer, @CL, everything works ok if I use bare `sqlite3.exe`. You can post this as the answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter of `substr()` was made optional in [SQLite 3.5.2](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_5_2.html).

You should get a newer version of SQLite Administrator (if possible), or use a more up-to-date tool like, e.g., [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).