# SQLite Get Weekday Date from Field

Tags: sqlite, date, dayofweek

I am trying to get the equivalent of this query in SQL in SQLite

SELECT DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(S.start_date)+1) DAY) AS pymtdate FROM subscriptions

The purpose of this is that I have a start date and a weekly payment. I want to calculate the weekly payments for the next N days (in the example above this is for one week) for a number of start dates. In SQLite the nearest I can get to is

SELECT date('now', 'weekday stftime('%w', S.start_date)') AS pymtdate FROM subscriptions

but this isn't working as it blows out when I try to combine the weekday with a calculated value.

Any suggestions?

I did find the answer using this post: [sqlite return as day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319302/sqlite-return-as-day-of-week)

```
SELECT S.subscription_id AS subid, 
case cast (strftime('%w',S.start_date) as integer)
when 0 then date('now' , 'weekday 0')
when 1 then  date('now' , 'weekday 1')
when 2 then  date('now' , 'weekday 2')
when 3 then  date('now' , 'weekday 3')
when 4 then  date('now' , 'weekday 4')
when 5 then  date('now' , 'weekday 5')
else date('now' , 'weekday 6') end as pymtdate
FROM subscriptions AS S
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, anything `'between quotes'` is a string.

You do not want the string `strftime(...)`, you want to execute this function, so you must write it outside the quotes (and append its return value to the other string):

```
SELECT date('now', 'weekday ' || strftime('%w', S.start_date)) ...
```

Comment: interesting manipulation of the string, well play :) , in my case i want to set Saturday as the start of the week and calculate **priceTotal** between saturday and friday ! any idea ?

Comment: @RAMM-HDR To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.